# JMeter how to create sha512sum?

Tags: jmeter, sha512

I'm new to scripting. I have the following use case: I need to check whether a message is sent with or without an attachment. I encountered a problem generating sha512. With which JMeter option is it possible to generate this and use it to send messages? I would be very grateful for your advice

In one of the sources I found that you can use JSR223 Sampler, in another PreProcessor JSR223. Both didn't work, maybe there was a Problem in the code I was trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

Your "didn't work" stanza doesn't tell the full story, going forward [consider providing sufficient amount of information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we could better understand your problem or reproduce your issue.

Coming back to your question, the easiest is going for [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest), something like:

```
${__digest(SHA-512,string-you-want-to-encode-here,,,)}
```

[image]

For JSR223 test elements you can do the same using [MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class instance, something like:

```
java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA-512').digest('foo'.getBytes()).encodeHex().toString()
```

[image]

More information on cryptographic operations in particular and Groovy scripting in JMeter in general:

- [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)